# letter in textview on android is too low

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I've developed a game, which has boxes of textview with 1 letter within it. 
in the emulator everything works fine, but, when i try to see it on my phone, the letter shifts down, and cuts the letter in the middle.

currently, my style is as so :

```
<style name="MoveLetter">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/BoxSize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/BoxSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_box_md_lighter</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/temp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">visible</item>
</style>
```

I use this style in my xml(partly) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/game7_336letters"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/woodbackground1lighter_a_rotated"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="240dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" android:layout_marginTop="175dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="240dp" android:layout_marginTop="175dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
<TextView style="@style/MoveLetter" android:id="@+id/game7_moveletter6"
    android:layout_marginLeft="300dp" android:layout_marginTop="175dp" android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

I've tried many options to add to the `style - PaddingBottom,PaddingTop, layout_gravity = center, gravity = layout_horizontal, gravity = layout_vertical : all` didn't help.

as far as right / left alignment - its good, the letter is in the center of the textview.

i'd appreciate any help you may have to offer..

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `textSize`, and make it smaller than your BoxSize dimen.  Different letters have different dimensions, so it will be tricky to get right across different density devices.

Answer (score 0):

incase anyone else has this issue : i figure out a way to pass the problem : 
if you set the padding on code behaind, problem solved (for me at least..)

```
TextView tv = findViewById(...);
tv.setPadding( 0, -25,0,0);
```